# Different wallpapers on monitors in Twinview with Wallch

Tags: desktop-background, twinview

Is there any way to set Wallch to rotate through different wallpapers on different monitors, using Twinview?  I'm assuming the same trick for workspaces doesn't work for monitors.
Thanks

Comment: It is quite hard for me to find at the web how you work with Twinview. Can you post a link on how you can have separate backgrounds with Twinview?

Comment: Actually, I'm not aware you can even have separate unchanging backgrounds with Twinview.

Comment: But you should find a working solution prior to trying to use it with a program...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing, no, there isn't. Whether or not you're using Twinview doesn't come into it.

Answer (score 0):

I found something for you.
It doesn't use Twinview or Wallch. :)
Here, take a look: http://ubuntuguide.net/ubuntu-11-04-unity-enable-different-wallpapers-in-each-workspaces

Ps.: If my answer was useful, please rate. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is about setting different wallpapers on different workspaces, rather than different monitors.

Comment: Oh, ok. Sorry about that. :) I misunderstood the question. :)